# Remove leading and trailing whitespaces between XML tags

Tags: xml, scala

I use standard scala xml library. This is simplified ouput:

```xml
<sitemapindex xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd">
<sitemap>
<loc> https://store.com/xmlsitemap?type=pages&page=1 </loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc> https://store.com/xmlsitemap?type=products&page=1 </loc>
</sitemapindex>
```

One method creates child element:

```scala
def childElements(pagesNumbers: Int): List[Elem] = 
(1 to pagesNumbers).map { i =>
//some logic
        <sitemap>
          <loc>{string}</loc>
        </sitemap>
}.toList
```

the other method just wrap what we receive:

```scala
    childElements(number).map { content =>
      <sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd">
        {content}
      </sitemapindex>
    }
```

I noticed when string inside `<loc>` tag consists of 69+ characters leading and trailing whitespaces automatically added like in example above. Otherwise, I have Elements without spaces.

I need `<loc>` tags to be always **without** whitespaces:

```xml
<loc>https://store.com/xmlsitemap?type=products&page=1</loc>
```

I tried to insert some additional attributes inside both `sitemapindex`  and `loc` tags (like `xsl:strip-space="default"`) but it doesn't work.

I tried to debug through the scala code and child element converted to text doesn't contain any whitespaces.

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: When you say the spaces were "automatically" added, we need to have some kind of idea what you were doing to make this happen. The only thing you've told us is that you are "using standard scala XML library" - but how are you using it?

Comment: @MichaelKay I edited my question with some more details

Comment: You can use XSLT transformation to remove leading and trailing spaces in the XML text nodes. As a postprocessing step after Scala's code finished its execution.

Answer (score 0):

I found scala xml PrettyPrinter `format` method further in the code which made those whitespases. They dissapeared when I removed it.